# Escape character for empty string

Tags: php, html, html-escape-characters

I have problem with a long product name :

```
TONER PRO HP LASERJET 1000/­1005/­1005W/­1200/­1220/­3300/­3310/­3320/­3330/­3380 C7115A (15A)
```

I need to break this product name on end of line,but my require is, allow only break after "/"

So result shold look like this:

```
TONER PRO HP LASERJET 1000/­1005/­1005W/­1200/­
1220/­3300/­3310/­3320/­3330/­3380 C7115A (15A)
```

I tried to replace character `"/"` with  `/&shy;` But it generates a hyphen in the end of line :(.

Does exist any escape character, what behave like empty string but allow me to break my string on specified place ?

Thank for any advice :)

Comment: you want the string to break like this:
**first line** `TONER PRO HP LASERJET 1000/­1005/`­
**next line** `1005W/­1200/­1220/­3300/­3310/­3320/­3330/­3380 C7115A (15A)`

Comment: In HTML? you'll have to use a <br /> tag

Answer (score 0):

For a forced line break, use `<br>` (if the string appears in a context where tags are allowed).

For a permitted line break (i.e., allowing the browser insert line break if needed), use either the nonstandard but widely supported `<wbr>` tag or the Unicode character ZERO WIDTH SPACE, U+200B, which can be written as `&#x200b;`.

You would need to repeat that at each permissible break point, e.g.

`TONER PRO HP LASERJET 1000/<wbr>­1005/­<wbr>1005W/<wbr>­1200/<wbr>­1220/<wbr>­3300/<wbr>­3310/­<wbr>3320/­<wbr>3330/­<wbr>3380 C7115A (15A)`

There are many [oddities in line breaking](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) in browsers, but the above should cover cases like this.

Comment: Thank you. Tag <wbr> was that what i looked for. I never use this tag before. Thank you